# AngularJS ng-click dynamic inside of ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I would like to load functions dynamically using my `ng-repeat`. I thought the below code would work but for some reason it is not working. Could someone please help me get the `add()` and `subtract()` functions to reference correctly.

Weird this is, when you inspect the HTML, then the functions where inserted correctly, but in the console Angular throws a weird error that I don't understand.

*Note: this is just a demo, I need to use this solution at a different place.*

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp">

<div ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <p>Click the button to run a function:</p>
  <button ng-repeat="x in options" ng-click="{{x.function}}">{{x.text}}</button>
  <p>The button has been clicked {{count}} times.</p>
</div>

<script>
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.count = 0;
    $scope.options = [
      { function: 'add()', text: 'Add'},
      { function: 'subtract()', text: 'Subtract'}
    ];
    $scope.add = function() {
      $scope.count++;
    };
    $scope.subtract = function() {
      $scope.count--;
    };
  }]);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did 2 things wrong.

1. The order of your code should be correct. (only for this plunker otherwise gives a compiling error) The functions should be created first, and then reference to those functions should be defined after that.
2. When you reference a function, remember to include `$scope` if it is a scoped function (eg. `$scope.add`). If it is not a scoped function, then just the function name is enough (eg. `add`).

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="myApp">

<div ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <p>Click the button to run a function:</p>
    <button ng-repeat="x in options" ng-click="x.function()">{{x.text}}</button>
    <p>The button has been clicked {{count}} times.</p>
</div>

<script>
    angular.module('myApp', [])
        .controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
            $scope.add = function () {
                $scope.count++;
            };
            $scope.subtract = function () {
                $scope.count--;
            };
            $scope.count = 0;
            $scope.options = [{
                    function: $scope.add,
                    text: 'Add'
                },
                {
                    function: $scope.subtract,
                    text: 'Subtract'
                }
            ];
        }]);
</script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: in ng-click it is not necessary to insert {{function}} because ng-click is angular's scope that knows that will called a function

Comment: Your point 1 doesn't matter hey, move your functions above the definitions and the code will still work. So I don't think point 1 is necessary :)

Comment: you are right, but in this example on the plunker gave me error where the order of functions were different. probably depens from compiler